# Flagging or Marking a Questions to Stick to Technology asked

Tags: discussion, flags

I have found when I try and ask a question on a particular technology, I get a lot of comments leaning towards the realm of, "Don't use X technology when Y might be better suited."  In some cases, the tools at hand dictate the technology and a specific way a solution can approached.  Sometimes the answer to the question asked might not be the most efficient, but it answered the specific asked question.

Is there a way to mark questions on SO so users answering the question shy away from those type of comments/answers, or should I just downvote answers that don't match?

Comment: You should not ask questions on theory on SO, I'd say. The [FAQ] is quite clear about that; ask practical questions instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, edited the post: theory might not have been the correct word choice.  When users ask about specifically one technology and get a lot of stuff about a different one then initially asked, this is the issue I am asking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should just address why you are limited to a specific technology, or only want input using that technology in the question so they know not to recommend others.

If you weren't specific about that, I wouldn't go downvoting good answers that use a different method.  Sometimes seeing the different ways the problem can be solved is helpful even if you can't use the solution.

Comment: I guess this makes sense, as it falls on me as the OP to phrase the question in a way to filter out answers.  Thanks, seems like I need to get better at wording/phrasing questions.  I try to make them generic enough to help others in the future, so I guess I should add in these other limitations to that.

Comment: @Bart I guess it's a good thing SO users go in the direction of efficiency in the times where a more elegant solution isn't apparent to me at the time of asking the question.  They are only looking to solve the problem in the best way possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that when you are programming something, that a view into the logic of other programs or other Logic has proven helpful, but I also agree that using the tags efficiently and pinpointing the issue will produce better answers to the problem at hand.